# Pydev won't Resolve Dynamically created Attributes

Tags: python, eclipse, dynamic, pydev, resolve

Greetings SO,

I have a weird problem that I don't seem to be able to solve:

I am working with the pydev plugin with eclipse Helios on Windows XP (if it matters).

I have a module which contains a class. The `__init__` of this class takes a parameter which determines the set of attributes that a method of this class should have.

Since I am not allowed to show actual code, I can give the following analogy:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, attrs):
        # attrs is a dictionary.
        # the keys of attrs are the names of attributes that this car should have
        # for example, a key of attr could be 'tires'

        # the values of attrs are the values of the attributes which are the keys
        # so if the key is 'tires', it's value might be 4
```

Now, since I'm setting these variables dynamically at runtime, Pydev is not able to give me suggestions when I do this:

```
c = Car()
print c.tires
```

When I type in "c." +, pydev does not offer tires as a suggestion.

How might I go about getting this functionality? Or is it just not something that pydev can do at present?

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Nobody could resolve dynamically created stuff in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to Imran for his solution. But, Ia better solution occurred to me:

```
Create all attributes in `__init__`.
When it comes time to be dynamic, delete the unwanted attributes.
```

This way, ene though the superset of all attributes is still suggested in the autocomplete, memory is not wasted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general problem which all dynamic language IDEs suffer. Pydev has no way of knowing what attributes `Car.__init__` sets on instances of Car, without executing your code. If you use class variables for the attributes you set in `__init__`, Pydev should be able to offer autocomplete suggstion.

```
class Car(object):
    tires = 4

    def __init__(self, attrs):
         self.tires = attrs.get('tires', self.tires)
         self.tires += attrs.get('spare', 0)
```

Comment: I'm already doing this (+1), but it feels so hacky. I'm wondering if there's a better way.